# Custom DependencyProperty in ObservableCollection<t>

Tags: wpf, collections, dependency-properties

How add custom DependencyProperty? This method does not work.

```
public class SongCollection : ObservableCollection<Song>
{
public static readonly DependencyProperty UrlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
  "Url", typeof(ObservableCollection<Point>), typeof(Arrow));
public Uri Url
        {
            get { return (Uri)GetValue(UrlProperty);}
            ....
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the problem should be that it doesn't compile. Since `ObservableCollection<T>` [is not derived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) from `DependencyObject`, this implementation cannot work, even if I would correct the rest of the code, which is also totally wrong.

For more information on `DependencyProperties` please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx).

**Edit**

The correct implementation of your property would be

```
public class SomeClass : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UrlProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Url", typeof(Uri), typeof(SomeClass));

    public Uri Url
    {
        get { return (Uri)GetValue(UrlProperty);}
        set { SetValue(UrlProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Edit 2**

The wrapper implementation

```
public class SomeClass : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty UrlProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Url", typeof(Uri), typeof(SomeClass), 
        new PropertyMeta(OnUrlChanged));

    public Uri Url
    {
        get { return (Uri)GetValue(UrlProperty);}
        set { SetValue(UrlProperty, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Song> Songs { get; set; }

    private static void OnUrlChanged (DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var wrapper = d as SomeClass;
        if (wrapper == null)
            return;

        // ... what ever you want to do with the collection
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem in **public class SomeClass : DependencyObject, ParentClass** -> multiple, not correct

Comment: Well correct is not the right word, it's simply not possible. Ok, I didn't clarify this, you cannot implement a `DependencyProperty` this way. What you can do is writing a wrapper. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Well you're welcome. Please note, that if a post is answering a question, it should be marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

DependencyProperties are used for exposing binding functonality on DependencyObjects.

Basically, you can't declare a DependencyProperty on a class that doesn't derive from DependencyObject, and also, you won't need to declare a DependencyProperty unless it's being used on a DependencyObject to be bound to a property in that object's DataContext.